# How to call a specific text file by giving only its name(not by giving full path for reading the file) from sub-directories in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, import

I want to read the specific text file by giving only its name(not full path) from the folder containing multiple sub-directories, in order to compare and merge the text files.

How to can I read the specific file using pandas ?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking for help with. Do you know how to recursively scan the files in your nested folders? Or are you asking for more specific help about how to do your comparison and merging of the file contents? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to search for the file and then work with it

```
import os
name = "Name of your file"
root= './' #Assuming you will search from current directory, you can give any path = []

for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for x in files:
        if x==name:
            path.append(os.path.join(dirpath, x))
print(path) #do your operation here
```

Comment: should not matter, just provide the parent folder's path in the 'root' variable if you are running the python file somewhere else.